# How to solve No module named 'apt_pkg' error on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64

Tags: apt, server, updates, dpkg

When I try sudo apt update command on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 this traceback comes. How can I fix it please

````
Traceback (most recent call last):                                        
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>                      
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", lin
e 11, in <module>                                                         
    import apt_pkg                                                        
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'                            
Reading package lists... Done                                             
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin
/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /u
sr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'                                     
E: Sub-process returned an error code```
````

Comment: Are you running some kind of script you wrote?

Comment: Nope, just installing packages and python libraries

Comment: Your question clearly shows a script is running not just a straight forward install of a package. What is the EXACT command you typed to get this error?

Comment: I just ran sudo apt update here is my result.  sudo apt update
[sudo] password for david: 
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:6 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,258 kB]

Comment: I was deployed a userbot on my server 6 days ago and was online through screen. Only ran it. Today when I wanted to re-run it saw that it gives library import errors and saw that all my requirement libraries has been uninstalled automatically. I tried to upgrade and update resources then try installing libraries and redeploy but encountered with this error on apt update

Comment: You need to stop this script. Why would you first tell me no script and then admit there is one? How can you be helped if you are not truthful?

Comment: Lol, I didn't say lie. I stopped that script and my bot wasn't functioning, then I do the apt update. That's why I'm asking for solution. Also when it's stopped that error comes. If I knew the solution why would I ask for help then